# How can I Force the use of a template-fileName when saving

Tags: excel, vba

here is what I need to do:

- Save with a specific format an excel file: CompagnyName_YYYYMMDD_Employe.xlsm
- I would like to keep the pop up window that ask me for the path because I need it to be OS - Windows compatible ,

That would make my day.

If it's impossible I would like to know anyway :)

Comment: What have you done so far? Please provide some code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this macro:

```
Sub CustomSave()
    Dim NewFileName As String
    NewFileName = "CompanyName_" & Format(Now, "YYYYMMDD") & "_Employee.xlsm"
    NewFileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(NewFileName, "Excel Macro Enabled Workbook (*.xlsm), *.xlsm")
    Call ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(NewFileName, xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled)
End Sub
```

Or use this to override the save event:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Cancel = True
    Dim NewFileName As String
    NewFileName = "CompanyName_" & Format(Now, "YYYYMMDD") & "_Employee.xlsm"
    ChosenFileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(NewFileName, "Excel Macro Enabled Workbook (*.xlsm), *.xlsm")
    If ChosenFileName <> False Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Call ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(ChosenFileName, xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled)
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that MAC users have an issue:

Run Time error: 1004
Method GetSaveAsFileName fo object _Application fail
continue/end/debug/help

...